# Use history.pushState while ignoring/bypassing .htaccess (alternative solution welcome)

Tags: html, ajax, .htaccess

What I'm trying to do is have a single dynamic file that takes a parameter to affect content (/view.html?k=about) but uses history.pushState to change the URL to something more user-friendly (ki/about). In addition, anytime an AJAX call is made on content.html to load new content, it updates the URL according, (e.g. if products are loaded via AJAX, change URL to keywords/products).

[image: My current solution with desired result]

My current solution is any path requested from ki is redirected via .htaccess to the view.html page. view.html then uses history.pushState to change the URL. As links are clicked, the URL updates. The problem with this, however, is it causes a infinite loop.

[image]

Here is my .htaccess file, residing in the /ki/ folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /concept/view.html?k=$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

What can I do to get my desired result? If there's a way to achieve the same thing without the .htaccess file then that's acceptable too.

Comment: Any reason not to have the webpage ki/about display the content in the first place? Not quite sure why we are using .htaccess or history.pushState

Comment: You are going to have to have the url point to the webpage someway or another, because when people share that user friendly url, you want them to be able to access the webpage.

Comment: @DrShenanigan The reason I can't just have ki/about display the content in the first place is because ki/about doesn't exist. Also the idea is that practically anything could be used (ki/map, ki/history, ki/products, ki/contact, etc...). It's possible there could be hundreds, thousands, or even tens of thousands of possible keywords to be used, and I don't want to create a html file for each possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to rewrite any url that goes in the form of ki/about to the /view.html?k=about behind the scenes.

history.pushState is only really meant to be used for web applictions like Spotify that don't reload the page but would still make sense to have the back button have some functionality. 
That way, urls can be shared without giving 404 pages.

I have not tested this but I am sure you want something like this

```
RewriteRule ^ki/([A-Za-z]+)/$ /view.html?ki=$1
```

If the user types in the ugly url, they will still get to the same page no problem. But the pretty urls will direct users to the right webpage.

For more info you can go here. 
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Comment: Exactly! Permanent redirects are the only ones that change the browser’s url bar. To handle a non-root `RewriteBase` and retain the pretty url’s query string, use `RewriteRule ^(/?)ki/([^./]+)$ $1concept/view.html?k=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I'm already doing? The problem with this when I call history.pushState it changes the URL properly but the RewriteRule loads view.html, with changes the URL, which triggers the RewriteRule, which loads view.html, which changes the URL, which triggers the RewriteRule, which loads view.html, which changes the URL, which triggers the RewriteRule, which loads view.html, which changes the URL  ... and on and on and on. It's an unending cycle, which freezes the page.

Comment: No, this is different from what you are doing. 

What you are doing is trying to change the URL with code that causes the page to reload. history.pushState is not really meant to do what you are using it for. 

All you need to do is use .htaccess to tell the server that when someone types in a "clean" url, it changes it to the "dirty" url and loads the page behind the scene. 

To the end user, all they see is the clean URL. No need to use javascript to change the URL client side unless you want to load a new page.